# Is there a way to change the font in tables of gtsummary package? Specifically, change it into Times New Roman font

Tags: r, fonts, gtsummary

I am making tables with descriptives for my master thesis and gtsummary gives the best output. However, the font differs from the one I want to use in writing (Times New Roman) and other tables in word that are an APA style - tables. I want to change the font in the tables from R, rather than changing the font of the whole text in my writing (it's a technical thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the font with the `gt::tab_options()` function. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

tbl <- 
  trial %>%
  select(age, grade) %>%
  tbl_summary() %>%
  as_gt() %>%
  gt::tab_options(table.font.names = "Times New Roman")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>